# "Not all paths return a value" errors in some of these functions — how to fix it?

Tags: c, generic-programming

I'm having problems writing this code. I'm not very familiar with returning back from functions.

I am trying to code with a z8 Encore microcontroller that I have interfaced with a dip, switch, and leds through a breadboard.

Basically I'm trying to write the code so that when I hit the test switch on the Z8 board it will access each function and then increment a single count output to the leds.

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. My compiler tells me that "not all paths return a value" in `button_pushed`, `pushed_button`, `released_button`. If someone can help me out it would be greatly appreciated!

```
#include <ez8.h>
#include <STDIO.H>

unsigned char pushed_button();
unsigned char released_button();
unsigned char dip;

void init_ports();
void button_pushed();
void mydelay(unsigned int msec);

void main()
{
     char count=0;

     init_ports();

    while(1)
    {
        dip=PDIN;

        button_pushed ();
        PEOUT=count;
        count++;;

        return (0);
    }
}


void button_pushed()
{
    unsigned char pushed_button;

    pushed_button=PCIN;
    pushed_button=pushed_button & 0x01;

    while(pushed_button==0x00)
    {
         return (0);
    }
}

unsigned char pushed_button()
{
    unsigned char pushed_button;

    pushed_button=PCIN;
    pushed_button=pushed_button & 0x01;

    while(pushed_button==0x01)
    {
         button_pushed();
    }
    if(pushed_button==0x00)
    {
        mydelay(2);

    }
    if(pushed_button==0x00)
    {
     return (0);
    }
}

unsigned char released_button()
{
    unsigned char pushed_button;

    pushed_button=PCIN;
    pushed_button=pushed_button & 0x01;

    while (pushed_button==0x00)
    {
        button_pushed();
    }
    if(pushed_button==0x01)
    {
        mydelay(2);
    }
    while(pushed_button==0x01)
    {
        return (0);
    }
}

void mydelay (unsigned int msec)
{
    long int delay;

    while(1)
    {
        for(delay=266666;delay>0;delay--);
    }

}

void init_ports(void)
{
    PEADDR=0x02;
    PECTL=0x00;
    PEADDR=0x01;
    PECTL=0x00;
    PEADDR=0x03;
    PECTL=0x00;
    PEADDR=0x00;

    PDADDR=0x02;
    PDCTL=0x00;
    PDADDR=0x01;
    PDCTL=0xFF;
    PDADDR=0x00;

    PCADDR=0x02;
    PCCTL=0x00;
    PCADDR=0x01;
    PCCTL=0x01;
    PCADDR=0x00;
}
```

Comment: Your compiler is telling you exactly what is wrong. All three of those functions specify that they return a value. For example, in `button_pushed` it's possible that if the first iteration of `pushed_button==0x00` evaluates to false then the program will hit the end of the function without returning any value.

Comment: Thanks David. The value of 0x00 is mean't to be seen while the program is running. I have masked the push button with a "0x01" and if the returned value is "0x00" I would like too call on the "mydelay" function and then repeat this statement and then call on the "released_button" function.

Comment: `char main()`.    Really?????    Also using a `while` statement, when the loop body only contains a `return` statement is unnecessary obfuscation.   A simple `if` will do.

Answer (score 0):

I know where my problem lies.
My knowledge of calling functions lacks understanding.

I tried taking out all the code from the init_ports function, put this code into the void main (void) and was able to compile & run another program in which the test switch on my programming kit was outputting on the leds when I pressed the switch, not an increment count (which is what I want) but the lighting would light up and switch between leds.

I've put the back all the initialization of ports back into the init_ports() function and now I have no output on the leds. Leading me to believe that there's something wrong with the way I'm using the functions? Or trying to call back from these functions. I'm not sure.